# highscore that will set text your score

Tags: android

i have a quiz game that has 3 questions/levels quiz game but how can i have a set text to my highscore to 2/3 or 1/3 or 3/3 if i clicked the button from my mainactivity.class. the flow of my code is this:
there is a highscore button on my mainactivity which is if you click it you will be intent in the highscore.class that will set text the score.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
Button highscore;
String highestScore;
int score;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
highscore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
highscore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override   
       public void onClick(View v) {

       SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
       if (score > preferences.getInt("score", 0)) {
            preferences.edit().putInt("score", score).commit();
       }
       Intent showHighScore = new Intent(MainActivity.this, highscore.class);
       showHighScore.putExtra("current_score", score);
       startActivity(showHighScore);
    }
});
}
}
```

highscore.class

```
public class highscore extends Activity {
Button back;
TextView highScore;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.highscore);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int currentScore = getIntent().getIntExtra("current_score", 0);
    highScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_highscore);
    highScore.setText(currentScore + " / " + preferences.getInt("score", 3));


    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override   
       public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Back",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
 });    
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Comment: `i already have a code but how can i make my set text to my high score to 2/3 or 1/3 or 3/3` can you explain more about this ? Do you want to set the text of a Textview when your button is clicked ?

Comment: if i clicked the button. my highscore classs will automatically have a 2/3 result

Comment: then what is the problem you have added onclick method save your result and just Call the HighScore class again when the call is received initialize the stored value to the Textview you want

Comment: from your code you are doing the right thing.are you getting any errors in your code?

Comment: my problem is simple hahaha. i just want to make the output of the textview to 1/3 when im running my code the output of the textview is 0/3

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentScore = getIntent().getIntExtra("current_score", 0)
```

You get a 0 here because the default is 0 if something goes wrong with your intent.

Make sure to set a score before

```
showHighScore.putExtra("current_score", score);
```

You can simply change

```
int currentScore = getIntent().getIntExtra("current_score", 0);
```

to

```
int currentScore = getIntent().getIntExtra("current_score", 999);
```

in order to see `999/3` so you know that something went wrong